# Integration With i

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Why does this approach to integration not work? If there is an integral $1/\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, the answer is $\arcsin(x/a)$. But if the integral is $1/\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ then it is $\log(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})$.

My question is, why can't we take $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and integrate as in the first case to get the answer as $-i \arcsin(x/a)$?

Comment: We can do it. There are some caveats - you need to know  arcsin$(x/a)$ for $x>a$;  one should really understand arcsin as a multivalued function of a complex variable to fully understand what's going on. But otherwise it's perfectly OK.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268591/how-to-derive-inverse-hyperbolic-trigonometric-functions

Comment: Thanks @labbhattacharjee, this helps me a lot! But it still doesn't exactly answer my question...could someone please elaborate? And in case it helps you answer, I have completed upto 12th standard level of Calculus in India, so the answer needn't be over explained. Thanks!

Comment: @RohanRao, added a solution here, too

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a\cosh A,$

$\implies \cos (iA)=\frac xa\implies iA=\arccos\frac xa=\frac\pi2-\arcsin\frac xa$

$\implies\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})$

$=\ln|a|+\ln(\cosh A+\sinh A)$

$=\ln|a|+\ln(e^A)$

$=\ln|a|+A$

$=\ln|a|+i(\frac\pi2-\arcsin\frac xa)$

$=-i\arcsin \frac xa+K$ where $K=\ln|a|+i\frac\pi2$ which is contant

Comment: @nbubis, $\cosh A=\frac{e^A+e^{-A}}2=\frac{e^{i(-iA)}+e^{i(iA)}}2=\cos(iA)$